# Не могу исправить ошибку

Tags: c#

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }
        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnenyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas. Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
            random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }
        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4,6)))

            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation,enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

CS1503  C# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.PropertyPath'

Comment: Вставьте текст ошибки с трассой в вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetproperty?view=netframework-4.8  Вы понимаете, что нам не видно номеров строк?

Comment: Теперь  нормально ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
```